# MS Exchange Transport Service won't start after IP stack reset

Tags: windows, email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2013

I'm running an exchange 2013 machine.
I was having some network problems and ended up resetting the network stack.
After a reboot, I reapplied the IP to the NIC and brought the machine back online.

Since then, the transport service and transport submission service will not start.

All the other exchange services are up and running.
I can log in to EAC and I can see my db is mounted and healthy.

I can also log on to OWA as a user and it logs in fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I'm pretty desperate at the minute :(

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this error I did the following

Opened the Exchange 2013 EAC
Goto Servers\
Clicked DNS lookups
External & Internal lookups were set to “All network adapters”
Change this to “Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2” (Choose the one that Exchange is using for external\internal network traffic (NOT iSCSI or DAG one)
Repeat on both External & Internal
Restart the “Microsoft Exchange Transport” and “Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Transport Submission” services